# What is the correct way to confirm a publish in celery?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I'm looking at tuning my celery/rabbitmq installation,  and I found this article:

http://www.lshift.net/blog/2015/04/30/making-celery-play-nice-with-rabbitmq-and-bigwig/

It mentions doing the setting `BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'confirm_publish': True}` if you want to guarantee message delivery (which I do).  I'm having trouble finding any documentation on this setting for either rabbitmq or celery.

What is the correct way to confirm a publish in celery with rabbitmq?  Where is the documentation for said feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So to answer my own question:  There is currently no documentation.

That said, I dug the source code for most of a morning and found the answer here:

https://github.com/celery/py-amqp/blob/24df1032db4a566e165f736ccb6b4a15cc94bcaa/amqp/channel.py#L1770-L1776

`py-amqp` is the library that celery ultimately uses (via kombu--two packages deep here folks!).  `py-amqp` reads that setting and has a wait when the `confirm_publish` option is set.  This effectively makes a queuing process synchronous.

Comment: As of now (August 2023), it seems the confirm_publish default is False for Celery, which means one has to set it to True manually: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5410

Answer (score 2):

`confirm_publish` option is used by `py-amqp` library https://github.com/celery/py-amqp
It forces publish to block connection until confirmation is received from RabbitMQ. 
RabbitMQ confirmations are described here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html