# How do confirm_publish and acks_late compare in Celery?

Tags: django, redis, rabbitmq, celery

I've noticed the following [in the docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#Task.acks_late):

> Ideally task functions should be idempotent: meaning the function won’t cause unintended effects even if called multiple times with the same arguments. Since the worker cannot detect if your tasks are idempotent, the default behavior is to acknowledge the message in advance, just before it’s executed, so that a task invocation that already started is never executed again.
>
> If your task is idempotent you can set the **acks_late** option to have the worker acknowledge the message *after* the task returns instead. See also the FAQ entry Should I use retry or acks_late?.
>
>
> If set to True messages for this task will be acknowledged after the task has been executed, not just before (the default behavior).
>
> Note: This means the task may be executed multiple times should the worker crash in the middle of execution. Make sure your tasks are idempotent.

Then there is the `BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'confirm_publish': True}` option [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35996065/562769). I could not find official documentation for that.

I want to be certain that tasks which are submitted to celery (1) arrive at celery and (2) eventually get executed.

Here is how I think it works:

- Celery stores the information which tasks should get executed in a broker (typically RabbitMQ or Redis)
- The application (e.g. Django) submits a task to Celery which immediately stores it in the broker. `confirm_publish` confirms that it was added (right?). If `confirm_publish` is set but the confirmation is missing, it retries (right?).
- Celery takes messages from the broker. Now celery behaves as a consumer for the broker. The consumer acknowledges (confirms) that it received a message an the broker stores this information. If the consumer didn't sent an acknowledgement, the broker will re-try to send it.

Is that correct?